# Is there any django app for realtime preview of markdown?

Tags: django, markdown

I'm using `django_markdown` to save the markdown text in django admin. Is there some better application which can show real-time preview as in stackoverflow while writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice any Django app which can handle that, but there is StackOverflow js library([pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/)) which can do it- you just have to replace widget in admin form.

Comment: You need to subclass [TextInput widget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L263) and write your own render method. One more thing- you probably will need to add static files of pagedown [in the admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions)

Comment: Thanks! Following your answer, I searched for an app and found this one: https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-pagedown

Answer (score 0):

http://thegoods.aj7may.com/django-bootstrap-markdown/

I developed this live preview markdown widget for Django.  I Used it for my blog.  I believe you could replace the textarea widget in the admin with this markdown widget.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this would be used?